# Got Expo suggest after starting project: If you want to resolve "package", use "module:package". what does this mean?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, twilio, webrtc

I have an expo react-native app and I am trying to use the `webrtc` package in the project. I followed the guide and got this message from expo:

> If you want to resolve `"react-native-twilio-video-webrtc"`, use `"module:react-native-twilio-video-webrtc"`

What does this message mean?